# Creating a file from a list with spaces

Tags: python

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sentence= ("I met a traveller from an antique land,Who said—“Two vast and trunkless legs of stoneStand in the desert. . . . Near them, on the sand,Half sunk a shattered visage lies, whose frown,And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command,Tell that its sculptor well those passions readWhich yet survive, stamped on these lifeless things,The hand that mocked them, and the heart that fed;And on the pedestal, these words appear:My name is Ozymandias, King of Kings;Look on my Works, ye Mighty, and despair!Nothing beside remains. Round the decayOf that colossal Wreck, boundless and bareThe lone and level sands stretch far away.").lower()
```

words = sentence.split(' ')

```
lst = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))
numberLst = []
for i in words:
   numberLst.append(lst.index(i)+1)

print(lst)
print (numberLst)

words_str = ''.join(words)
numberLst_str = ''.join(str(e) for e in numberLst)

file = open("words.txt","w")
file.write(words_str)
file.close()

file=open("numberlst.txt","w")
file.write(numberLst_str)
file.close()

joinlst = " ".join(lst[i-1] for i in numberLst)

print (joinlst)

file=open("joinlst.txt","w")
file.write(joinlst)
file.close()
```

Hello, i have a problem with my words file that i have created in my code and it is that when i connect all of the words in my list it is written into the file like this:  imetatravellerfromanantiqueland,whosaid—“twovastandtrunklesslegsofstonestandinthedesert....nearthem,onthesand,halfsunkashatteredvisagelies,whosefrown,andwrinkledlip,andsneerofcoldcommand,tellthatitssculptorwellthosepassionsreadwhichyetsurvive,stampedontheselifelessthings,thehandthatmockedthem,andtheheartthatfed;andonthepedestal,thesewordsappear:mynameisozymandias,kingofkings;lookonmyworks,yemighty,anddespair!nothingbesideremains.roundthedecayofthatcolossalwreck,boundlessandbaretheloneandlevelsandsstretchfaraway.

The problem is that there are no spaces between the words written in the file so it is hard to identify the words in the file. once fixed it would preferably look like this : (i:met:a:traveller:from:an:antique:land)(just as an example)

if you could please help it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm not following what you want? do you want to just write the words out separated by `:`?

Comment: You appear to be joining words with an empty string in `''.join(words)`. Just add the colon in there, so `':'.join(words)`. But then you correctly use a single space later on with `joinlst = " ".join(lst[i-1] for i in numberLst)` so I'm not sure if I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when you join the words at the beginning you use ''. You should change that line from:

```
words_str = ''.join(words)
```

to:

```
words_str = ' '.join(words)  # Separates the words with spaces
```

If you want it separated by regular spaces, or

```
words_str = ':'.join(words)  # Separates the words with ':'
```

If you want it separated by ':'